# I want to Create a function that returns the number of employees in a department

Tags: sql, function, group-by, oracle11g

The query I tried is this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dno (d_no IN Employee.DepartmentNo%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  d_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO d_cnt 
  FROM employee GROUP BY DeptNo=d_no;

  RETURN d_cnt;
END get_dno;
```

and use this query below to get value from user.

```
DECLARE
  get_dptno NUMBER;
BEGIN
  get_dptno := get_dno(:d_no);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No of employees in searched DeptNo : ' ||get_dptno);
END;
```

But I couldn't even get the Function part to run.

The error I got was where I used GROUP BY, I think

[This is the error message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQbuX.png)

Is there any workaround for the same logic ???

Answer (score 0):

When you group by column there is no condition accept please remove code after column name `DeptNo`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dno (d_no IN Employee.DepartmentNo%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  d_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO d_cnt 
  FROM employee GROUP BY DeptNo;

  RETURN d_cnt;
END get_dno;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you want `WHERE` rather than `GROUP BY` and you need to work out if the column name is `DepartmentNo` or `DeptNo` and use the correct column name in the signature and in the `SELECT` query:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_dno (
  d_no IN Employee.DepartmentNo%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  d_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   d_cnt 
  FROM   employee
  WHERE  DepartmentNo=d_no;

  RETURN d_cnt;
END get_dno;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  get_dptno NUMBER;
BEGIN
  get_dptno := get_dno(:d_no);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No of employees in searched DeptNo : ' ||get_dptno);
END;
/
```

Works and, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (id, departmentno) AS
SELECT  1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

If `:dno` is `1` then outputs:

> ```
> No of employees in searched DeptNo : 4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6608fdc726d04367918c6259adb18669)*